# Required Information for Alexa waiting time

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

1. Wants to know for how much time Alexa Echo device wait after speaking speak_output message before      re-prompting again ?
2. Also wants to know after user start giving reply for how much time Alexa give time to user, to accept voice commands from user ?

For Example :
1)
User : "Invoking Alexa skill"
Alexa : "Welcome message"
Wait time before re-prompting message again
User : Did not reply any command

2)
User : "Invoking Alexa skill"
Alexa : "Welcome message"
User : "Any reply"
Alexa : "Ask any question to user"
User : "Answering long voice command........"

For how much long time user can give voice command to alexa.

Comment: I just tested my Alexa device by saying "Alexa" with no command.  The blue ring lit up for  5 seconds, then went dark.

Answer (score 0):

1. After the original prompt ends and the microphone opens, the user has 8 seconds to say something.   If Alexa hears nothing, the reprompt (if any) plays, the mic opens again and the user has another 8 seconds to respond.  If Alexa still hears nothing, the skill session is (silently) closed.
2. I haven't found any *documented* limit for how long the mic stays open once the user starts speaking. I've tested this by reading a page of a novel into an `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot. Up to about 100 words, the input was accepted without a problem.  It's unnatural though - you have to speak very quickly, without no pauses or stumbling, like a cattle auctioneer.  If Alexa detects a pause, you're deemed to have finished; the mic closes and your input is processed as a complete response.